# Image displays differently in Chrome and in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Newbie web developer here! I have a logo embedded in a navigation bar which is showing differently in Chrome vs. in IE version 10 running document standards. The page is running bootstrap CSS. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="masthead">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav">
           <li><img class="" src="img/logo.png" style="height: 50px;"></li> 
                    <li><a href="team.htm">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.htm">Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="charity.htm">Charity</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="past.htm">Past</a></li>
                    <li><a href="talk.htm">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.htm">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
```

In IE the output is expected, like this (ignore the black box, that's me censoring my employer):
[image: ignore the black box, that's my employer]

In Chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

The CSS for the image under `bootstrap.css` and list is as follows:

```
img {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 0;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }

li {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Following multiple suggestions to try stating a width, I put in "width: 100px;" after the 'height' in the html code. The image resizes correctly in IE10 but maxes out at 64px on chrome. Looking at `Computed Style` shows:

[image]

Comment: Should post your style too and make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: why was there a downvote and a vote to close?

Comment: Have you tried adding a Width to the logo?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the image dimension attributes like this:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" height="50" width="100">
```

Height and width should be that of the image

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the image width as 100% may be that will help.

Try to change the style like this.

```
width:100%;
background-size:100%;
```

Comment: then set the width as auto, try alternate things, dont worry it will help you

Comment: what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to make the image look like the first result (where it is nicely stretched out) instead of the second result (where it is squashed). The 2nd result is what the site looks like in Chrome, 1st result is from IE10 running doc standards. Your solution doesn't work. The image outputs the same - the width is stuck at 64px no matter what I do, BUT ONLY IN CHROME! :(

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
img
{
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 0;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

instead of:

```
img {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
border: 0;
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
```

Comment: see edited answer, I think it's auto? or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine I see, I think I misunderstood the problem

Comment: Doesn't work. The image outputs the same - for some reason the width is hardlocked to 64px no matter what I do, BUT ONLY IN CHROME! :(